# Moving Access tables to SharePoint: IDs changed

Tags: list, access

I moved all my Access table to SharePoint lists. The problem I found when doing this is that SharePoint changed the ID of many elements of my tables, leaving no gaps between them. For example, my Table had:

```
ID NAME
1 A
2 B
4 C
5 D
```

And now my list has

```
ID NAME
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
```

But I need the ID of C to be 3, because I have other tables that use that ID as a reference.

I can't find any solution to this problem. Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 1):

The ID field is a system field. It is automatically incremented and is unique within a particular list. This field can't be changed.

You can create a new field and map it to your ID column.